# node-add-on-api c/c++ code cannot access a file in docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, node-addon-api

We have created a docker container in which we put our NodeJS code and C bindings, the JS code is supposed to send a file address to the C bindings and the C-code should read the file and process the results. The file resides in the path outside the srv/xxx/yyy/zzz path. this volume is mounted and the JS can read and write the file with no issues, but when passed to the C bindings, somehow the for C bindings the file is not visible.

Not sure if I need to add extra configuration for node-add-on api... some one help